# CPU frequency won't go beyond 800MHz on my Dell XPS 13 with ivybridge

Tags: linux, cpu-frequency

I cannot go beyond 800MHz on my Dell XPS 13 Ivybridge CPU.

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1000 MHz and 2.60 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Even if issue `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance` I still get 800MHz.
Then I tried

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-set -f 2.60GHz
Setting cpu: 0
Error setting new values. Common errors:
- Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
- Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
- Trying to set an invalid policy?
- Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
   for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
   or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?
```

...no luck.
My laptop is slow especially when running on battery.
I saw that there was an open bug [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58001) which seems to be similar to my experience but it was closed for not enough info.
Can someone help me please?

**EDIT:**

I booted with the `intel_pstate=disable` option and now I can set frequencies and governors. However my laptop is still slow and unresponsive even in performance mode, so there's something else giving problems.

Comment: could be that your charger has failed and is no longer recognized as a Dell(tm) charger. When that happens my latitude d630 locks itself to 800mhz, too, and refuses to charge.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the `userspace` module

```
sudo modprobe cpufreq_userspace
```

and set the governor

```
cpupower frequency-set --governor userspace
```

The files in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ provide information and a means of controlling the frequency scaling subsystem. Seed values are given in Khz. You need to be root to access the /sys filesystem.

Example:

Your max speed is at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq`.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
700000
```

Your min speed is at /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
500000
```

you can write to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed to change the current speed.

```
echo 700000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed

cat /proc/cpuinfo

cpu MHz  : 697.252

echo 900000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
cat /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz  : 976.152
```

To get more informations how to change frequency

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling

To show frequency and more informations try to install **i7z**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i7z
```

to run i7z type: `sudo i7z`

Comment: `Permission denied` `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: @Cerin Use `sudo`